# Absolute Phrase or Participle Phrase?

Tags: participle-phrases, absolute-construction

So I'm a bit confused. Is this sentence a participle phrase or absolute phrase? And whats the difference?

> **Having eaten very late**, the children became sleepy right after dinner.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an absolute clause because it has no subject. It's a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct. - BillJ

Answer (score 1):

> [*Having eaten very late*], *the children became sleepy right after dinner.*

The bracketed element is a participial clause functioning as an adjunct, but it doesn't qualify as an absolute because it doesn't contain a subject.

Absolutes are loosely attached non-finite clauses and, importantly, they have no syntactic link to the main clause, hence the requirement for a subject.